# Changing appearance of WooCommerce product layout

Tags: themes, plugins

I'm new to WooCommerce and my products are currently being laid out with a thumbnail, product title, and price. Ideally I would like to have them horizontal, with a small excerpt to the right of the image.

Now, can this be done within the WooCommerce interface, or will I have to add functions to the PHP and then style with CSS? I couldn't find anything in the documentation to answer this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed something that you need to make a specific page template for. Just CSS won't do the trick because you need to add a function to your functions.php file (in your theme or [**child-theme**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) folder) to display the excerpt.

You could do something like this:

```
add_action( 'wp' , 'add_excerpt', 20);

function add_excerpt() {
    if ( is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() ) {
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 5);
    }
}
```

Which will add the excerpt to the product listings.